# Segmentation Fault, Array Printing C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a program that takes user-input strings and prints them out as a 7 by 5 asterisk grid. I am currently trying to figure out how to print put the letters as I need to print them line by line in order for the different letters to be printed side by side.

Anyway, my attempt so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char capitalA[7][5] = { 
"  *  ",
" * * ",
"*   *",
"*****",
"*   *",
"*   *",
"*   *"
};
int i;
int j;

int main() 
{//main

    for (i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 7 ; j++) 
        {
            printf("%s\n", capitalA[j][i]);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}//*main
```

My desired output is the asterisk A, but I get a Segmentation fault.

Comment: %s --> %c (voting to close as a typo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char capitalA[7][5]
```

is not large enough. The strings literals you use in the initialization automatically include the `\0` character, so you need to use

```
char capitalA[7][6]
```

instead. And change your loops to a single one

```
for (j = 0; j < 7 ; j++)
    printf("%s\n", capitalA[j]);
```

since right now you are displaying `char`s using `%s` specifier.

If you're not happy with the `'\0'` being added automatically and need to save space, you can use the code you currently have or you need to initialize the array using brace initialization like

```
char capitalA[7][5] = {{' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' '}, ...};
```

and stick to displaying the characters `char` by `char` (making sure that you use the `'%c'` specifier instead of the `'%s'`).

Comment: @MiguelRestrepo It should work fine, see the live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35055d7c9bbc25ae).

Comment: Well then I don't know what is wrong with my compiler, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @MiguelRestrepo Did you do *exactly* what vsoftco told to? Could you share your new code which segfaults?

Comment: @MiguelRestrepo Can you copy paste the code in the live example I just linked and try it? There is no reason to get a segfault.

Comment: Wow, that was stupid. I'm sorry, I forgot to remove the [i] from the printf statement after deleting the i for loop.

Comment: If the OP uses, `char capitalA[7][5] = {{' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' '}, ...};` , then `printf("%s\n", capitalA[j]);` will not be ok as it exhibits UB. BTW, the OP's code in the question does not add the `\0` and can be used instead of rewriting the code using braces and stuff.

Comment: @CoolGuy Correct, when I edited it didn't realize that interferes negatively with the content, so re-edited.

Comment: @CoolGuy The larger initializer is wrong in C++, but fine in C, and I thought the same rules apply to C, but you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 7 ; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", capitalA[j][i]);
}
}
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("%c", capitalA[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

because

1. The correct format specifier for a `char` is `%c`, not `%s`.
2. You mixed up the loops. The outer one should loop 7 times while the inner one should loop 5 times.
3. You should print a `\n` *after* the inner loop has finished executing and not in each iteration of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%s\n", capitalA[j][i]);
```

should be

```
printf("%c", capitalA[j][i]);
```

What you need is to print character by character but you are trying to print a string using `%s` which tries to print a string until `\0` is encountered.

Since `%s` is trying to access array out of bound you see a segmenation fault.

If you want to go with printing char by char then make sure you insert `\n` after each row

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) 
 {
    for (j = 0; j < 7 ; j++) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", capitalA[j][i]);
    }
 }
```

You are printing char type array. Not a single character. Change it to

```
for (i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < 7 ; j++) 
    {
        printf("%c", capitalA[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This prints each character and then start a newline. Which means I get blank lines and lines with single asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

just use one for loop, and change 5 to 6 in the array declaration like this :

```
char capitalA[7][6]
//  and
for(j=0 ; j<7 ; j++)
    printf("%s\n",capitalA[j]);
```

your program will be like this after modification, try it ^^:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//edit the column nomber to support the '\0' it will be 6 not 5.
char capitalA[7][6] = { 
"  *  ",
" * * ",
"*   *",
"*****",
"*   *",
"*   *",
"*   *"
};
int i;
int j;

int main() 
{//main


        for (j = 0; j < 7 ; j++) 
        {
            printf("%s\n", capitalA[j]);
        }

    return (0);
}//*main
```